# Postgres jsonb_set and jsonb_insert not appending value into nested object

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble inserting a value into a json object that is nested in a jsonb column.

The structure of the jsonb is this

```
{
"insight": {}, 
"view_name": "foobar", 
"chart_info": {
    "user": "Some User"
}, 
"metric_name": "MetricForUser"
}
```

My goal is to insert into the chart_info object this:

```
"chart_info": {
    "user": "Some User"
    "sub_series_id": "merger" 
}
```

I've tried using both jsonb_insert and jsonb_set but neither is giving the expected results.

```
UPDATE "tablename"
   SET "jsonb_column" = jsonb_insert("tablename"."jsonb_column", '{chart_info, sub_series_id}', '"merger"', false)
 WHERE id in (25, 26, 27)
 
UPDATE "tablename"
   SET "jsonb_column" = jsonb_set("tablename"."jsonb_column", '{chart_info, sub_series_id}', '"merger"', false)
 WHERE id in (25, 26, 27)
```

Comment: The first one does what you want for me.  The 2nd one also works, if you change the last argument to `true`.

Comment: @jjanes Neither of those is actually updating the column, with true or false.

Comment: As I say, works for me.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e311f622def92c9dad719eb6ec09ba1

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following statement:

```
update test set name = 
jsonb_set( jsonb_in          => name, -- your column name 
           path              => array['chart_info'], -- chart_info object 
           replacement       => '{"user": "Some User","sub_series_id": "merger" }', -- new json for chart_info that need to be updated
           create_if_missing => false);
```

if you have as input parameter only : {"sub_series_id": "merger"} you can try the following statement then  :

```
update test set name = 
jsonb_set( jsonb_in       => name,
           path              => array['chart_info'],
           replacement       => name -> 'chart_info'||'{"sub_series_id": "merger"}',
           create_if_missing => false);
```

You can check the following link : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html